# how to design a buffered tcp publisher/subscriber in scala playframework / akka

Tags: scala, sockets, tcp, playframework, akka

We are in the process in moving away from a python based environment to scala play framework one and I have to write a buffered publisher subscriber which will interface with another system written in python. The goal here is to write a publisher which would take messages from a buffer/queue and send them to a server over a tcp socket and keep the socket opened so we can reuse it later.

Our old python publisher created a socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) socket which would never close, and worked with a scheduler to take messages off the queue and send them over the streaming socket.

I'm interested in using akka streaming io, but I don't know how to create a streaming socket that works with a scheduler periodically looking at a queue and sending message to a server.

If anyone has a code sample that could illustrate how this could be done in scala/play framework/akka streaming io that would be awesome.

Thanking you in advance
Francis

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want Akka TCP:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/io-tcp.html